# Laravel FrozenNode Auth::check() always return False

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

`Laravell 5.2` and `FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator 5.0.11`.

Try to use:

```
'domain' => '',
'middleware' => array(),
   'permission'=> function()
        {
            return Auth::check();
        }
```

in `config/administrator.php`, but always get `"False"`. In other places returns `"True"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the admin routes provided by FrozenNode are not inside the `web` middleware group, therefore they do not include any of the session information. No session, no logged in user.

You can easily fix this, however, by adding `'web'` to the `middleware` key in your config file:

```
'domain' => '',
'middleware' => array('web'), // add 'web' middleware group
'permission'=> function() {
    return Auth::check();
}
```